# google analytics regular expression advanced segment

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a page that displays details of a program, I want to set an advanced segment in google analytics to only return pages that contain

```
/program/view/path_to_program
```

so only program detail pages display, the third segment pages are the only pages I want to display in the google analytics results.

I know this will take some sort of regular expression and I am not very familiar with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Analytics Regular Expression Help Page](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55582)
Not exactly sure what you want to match but /program/view/[a-Z]+ might work.